# Using Spark window function lead to create column in dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to create a new column with value of the previous date(date less the current date) for group of ids for the below dataframe

```
+---+----------+-----+
| id|      date|value|
+---+----------+-----+
|  a|2015-04-11|  300|
|  a|2015-04-12|  400|
|  a|2015-04-12|  200|
|  a|2015-04-12|  100|
|  a|2015-04-11|  700|
|  b|2015-04-02|  100|
|  b|2015-04-12|  100|
|  c|2015-04-12|  400|
+---+----------+-----+
```

I have tried with lead window function .

```
val df1=Seq(("a","2015-04-11",300),("a","2015-04-12",400),("a","2015-04-12",200),("a","2015-04-12",100),("a","2015-04-11",700),("b","2015-04-02",100),("b","2015-04-12",100),("c","2015-04-12",400)).toDF("id","date","value")

 var w1=Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date".desc)
 var leadc1=lead(df1("value"),1).over(w1)
 val df2=df1.withColumn("nvalue",leadc1)

+---+----------+-----+------+                                                   
| id|      date|value|nvalue|
+---+----------+-----+------+
|  a|2015-04-12|  400|   200|
|  a|2015-04-12|  200|   100|
|  a|2015-04-12|  100|   300|
|  a|2015-04-11|  300|   700|
|  a|2015-04-11|  700|  null|
|  b|2015-04-12|  100|   100|
|  b|2015-04-02|  100|  null|
|  c|2015-04-12|  400|  null|
+---+----------+-----+------+
```

But as we can see when I have same date in id "a" I am getting wrong result.The result should be like

```
+---+----------+-----+------+                                                   
| id|      date|value|nvalue|
+---+----------+-----+------+
|  a|2015-04-12|  400|   300|
|  a|2015-04-12|  200|   300|
|  a|2015-04-12|  100|   300|
|  a|2015-04-11|  300|  null|
|  a|2015-04-11|  700|  null|
|  b|2015-04-12|  100|   100|
|  b|2015-04-02|  100|  null|
|  c|2015-04-12|  400|  null|
+---+----------+-----+------+
```

I already have a solution using join although I am looking for a solution using window function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have multiple rows with the same date.  `lead` will take `value` from the next *row* in the result set, not the next *date*.  So when you sort the rows by date in descending order, the next row could be the same date.

How do you identify the correct value to use for a particular date?  for example why are you taking 300 from (id=a, date=2015-04-11), and not 700?

To do this with window functions you may need to do multiple passes - this would take the last `nvalue` and apply it to all rows in the same id/date grouping - but I'm not sure how your rows are initially ordered.

```
 val df1=Seq(("a","2015-04-11",300),("a","2015-04-12",400),("a","2015-04-12",200),("a","2015-04-12",100),("a","2015-04-11",700),("b","2015-04-02",100),("b","2015-04-12",100),("c","2015-04-12",400)).toDF("id","date","value")

var w1 = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date".desc)
var leadc1 = lead(df1("value"),1).over(w1)
val df2 = df1.withColumn("nvalue",leadc1)
val w2 = Window.partitionBy("id", "date").orderBy("??? some way to distinguish row ordering")
val df3 = df1.withColumn("nvalue2", last_value("nvalue").over(w2))
```